# updating the value of a key in a std::map

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary

Assume we have a simple structure such as the following

```
struct T{
  int x;
  int y;
};
T t1, t2;
```

Also assume that I have a `map<T, int> myMap` and that two structures of type `T` are compared using their `x` values only. I.e. `t1 < t2` iff `t1.x < t2.x`. I am trying to update some of the `y` values of the keys over myMap. This should not affect how the map is seeing the keys. Is there any way other than removing the old element and inserting a new one?

Comment: Why is the key `T` rather than a simple `int`? You might want to explain what `x` and `y` mean and why it *makes sense* to use `T` rather than an `int` as the key.

Comment: @David: Exactly. My point. Hence, my suggestion.:-)

Comment: I just simplified my question. The original object which works as the key for my map has far more attributes and is used in way more contexts that I cannot separate attributes based on only the condition of being the key of the map.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you are sure that `y` does not participate in the "logical state" of your class and is merely an implementation detail, then you could declare it `mutable`:

```
struct T
{
  int x;
  mutable int y;
  bool operator<(const T& rhs) const { return x < rhs.x; }
};
```

Now you ought to be able to change `y`:

```
for (auto it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); ++it)
{
  it->first.y = -2; // ouch? But it won't invalidate the map's invariants.
}
```

Answer (score 10):

No, `map` cannot let you modify the keys, because that could invalidate the map invariant (ordering of the elements) — you know it won't, but the `map` cannot know that, so it errs on the side of caution and disallows that.

Remove and reinsert is a proper way to do it. Treat keys as immutable.

Answer (score 4):

If `y` doesn't participate in the comparison, you can mark it as `mutable`, so it can be modified even when the value is constant.

Answer (score 1):

The keys of `std::map` are const. So you cannot change it.

Also, if you use only `x` to compare the keys, then why do you `std::map<T,int>`?  Why not this:

```
std::map<int, std::pair<T,int> > data; //where keys would be t.x
```

After all, in your map, keys are effectively `t.x`.

Comment: What about making the `y` member `mutable`, though? Since it "logically" leaves the object invariant?

Comment: @Kerrek SB, may be you should post that as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can modify `T::y` if it does not affect comparison operator behaviour. On the other hand it is bad style to modify map's key, it should be immutable. Some implementations of Standard Library do allow to modify key.

Comment: "Some implementations of Standard Library do allow to modify key." Those implementations are broken (or, don't implement the Standard Library, if you prefer.) Can you name them?

Answer (score 0):

keys are const in a map, try copying new values into a new map.

Answer (score 0):

Like Cat said you shouldn't change keys for a lot of good reasons but you seem to know enough to move ahead.

Cast away the key's constness with const_cast and you can't do all kinds of damage.... err changes.  Just double check that the comparison operator still returns the same after modifying it.

Comment: I was going to say this was a bad idea, but it might make sense if selectively making `mutable` the `struct`'s non-key members could cause issues in non-`map` situations. Both are bad ideas, let's face it, but one might be slightly less bad than the other, depending on the context. ;-)